# multithreading LRUcache in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading

I want to implement a multithreading LRU cache in C++. And here is the code. Can you tell me what should I do to make it more multithreading?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <mutex>
using namespace std;
class LRUCache {
public:
    class Node {
    public:
        int key,val;
        Node* left,*right;
        Node(int _key,int _val):key(_key),val(_val),left(NULL),right(NULL) {}
    }*L,*R;
    unordered_map<int,Node*> m;
    int n;
    mutex mtx;
    condition_variable cv;
    void insert(Node* node)
    {
        Node* next=L->right;
        L->right=node;
        node->right=next;
        node->left=L;
        next->left=node;
    }
    void erase(Node* node) {
        node->left->right=node->right;
        node->right->left=node->left;
    }
    LRUCache(int capacity) {
        n=capacity;
        L=new Node(-1,-1),R=new Node(-1,-1);
        L->right=R;
        R->left=L;
    }

    int get(int key) {
        mtx.lock();
        if(m.count(key)==0) {mtx.unlock();return -1;}
        Node* node=m[key];
        erase(node);
        insert(node);
        cout<<"get:"<<node->val<<endl;
        mtx.unlock();
        return node->val;
    }

    void put(int key, int value) {
        mtx.lock();
        if(m.count(key)) {
            m[key]->val=value;
            erase(m[key]);
            insert(m[key]);
        } else {
            Node* node=new Node(key,value);
            if(m.size()==n) {
                Node* tmp=R->left;
                erase(tmp);
                m.erase(tmp->key);
            }
            insert(node);
            m[key]=node;
        }
        cout<<"put:"<<value<<endl;
        mtx.unlock();
    }

    void putcache() {
        for(int i=1;i<=10;i++) {
            put(i,i+10);
            this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
        }
    }

    void getcache() {
        for(int i=1;i<=10;i++) {
            get(i);
            this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
        }
    }
};


int main() {
    LRUCache c1(100);
    std::thread t1(&LRUCache::putcache,&c1);
    std::thread t2(&LRUCache::getcache,&c1);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't `using namespace std;`, especially in headers - that brings every identifier from `std` into the global namespace, from every header that's included (and that set of identifiers is subject to change with future standards).  We have namespaces for a reason - let's use them!

This program doesn't compile, because `condition_variable` is not defined.  If that's intended to be `std::condition_variable`, then we need to include `<condition_variable>` before using it.

It doesn't make sense to have all the members declared `public`.  That means we have no control over the class's invariants, and any of its state can be modified unsafely.

Why are we using `std::cout` in member functions `get()` and `put()`?  I wouldn't want my program's standard output stream corrupted like that (to be honest, I wouldn't want such tracing even on `std::clog` unless specifically requested).  And don't flush the stream (with `std::endl`) when that's not necessary - just use a plain newline.

There's a risk of memory leak here:

> ```
>     L=new Node(-1,-1),R=new Node(-1,-1);
> ```

If the creation of the second `Node` fails, then we lose the one and only reference to the first (i.e. `L`), and are unable to `delete` it.

We have an even bigger memory leak, since no `Node` ever gets deleted at all.

Why do we have arbitrary sleeps in the `putcache()` and `getcache()` member functions?  I don't see any benefit to delaying these operations.

Instead of manually locking and unlocking the mutex `mtx`, prefer `std::lock_guard`, which will unlock the mutex in all return paths, including when an exception is thrown.

`Node` requires (possibly deleted) copy and assignment operators, as copies shouldn't be sharing the pointers `left` and `right`.  Similarly, `LRUCache` needs those members, due to its pointers `L` and `R`.  Initialise its members, rather than letting them default-initialise and then overwriting in the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

## Make more use of the standard library

You are leveraging `std::unordered_map` to provide \$O(1)\$ lookups, but you have manually implemented a linked list to keep track of which nodes were most recently used. You can use [`std::list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) to do this for you. In fact, the list will store both the keys and values, while the `std::unordered_map` will map keys to entries in the list. You can make use of the guarantee that list iterators will not be invalidated, even if elements in a list are added or (re)moved. The [`splice()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/splice) function can be used to move an element to the front.

```cpp
class LRUCache {
    std::list<std::pair<int, int>> nodes;
    using node_iterator = decltype(nodes)::iterator;
    std::unordered_map<int, node_iterator> index;
    std::mutex mtx;
    std::size_t n;

    void update(node_iterator node_it) {
        nodes.splice(nodes.begin(), nodes, node_it);        
    }

public:
    LRUCache(std::size_t n): n(n) {}

    void put(int key, int value) {
        std::lock_guard lock(mtx);

        if (auto it = index.find(key); it != index.end()) {
            auto node_it = it->second;
            node_it->second = value;
            update(node_it);
        } else {
            nodes.emplace_front(key, value);
            index[key] = nodes.front();

            if (nodes.size() > n) {
                index.erase(nodes.back().first);
                nodes.pop_back();
            }
        }
    }

    int get(int key) {
        std::lock_guard lock(mtx);

        if (auto it = index.find(key); it != index.end()) {
            update(it->second);
            return it->second->second;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }
};
```

There are other variations possible, see for example [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504178/lru-cache-design).

## Ambiguous return value

There is a problem with `get()`: if it returns -1, it is not possible to tell whether this was because the key was not found, or if the key was found but the value was set to -1. Consider adding another way to report whether or not the key was found. A good way in C++17 or later is to use [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) for the return value.

## Make it a template

Your cache is hardcoded to use `int` for both keys and values. What if you want to have `std::string` keys and `float` values? You can easily make your cache work with any type of key and value by making it a template:

```cpp
template<typename Key, typename Value>
class LRUCache {
    std::list<std::pair<Key, Value>> nodes;
    ...

public:
    void put(const Key& key, const Value& value) {
        ...
    }

    std::optional<Value> get(const Key& key) {
        ...
    }
};
```